# How do I invoke an ActiveX control's property page?

Tags: c++, activex

I have created an ActiveX control that uses five different colors.  I would like to the control's property page to let the user choose the R, G and B values for each of the five colors.  That won't be a problem.  My problem is:  how do I display the property page?  For the sake of this question, let's say I want to connect it to the control's double-click event.  The user would double-click on the control and the property page dialog box would appear.  What code would have to be in the event handler to do that?

And yes, I know I'm working with antique technology.  So is the rest of my company, and far too many other companies.

In case it matters, I'm writing the control in C++ using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have not been able to find anything at all that would suggest how to do this, so I haven't tried anything.  The only thing I found was this quote from a Microsoft help page:  "When the control’s Properties verb (OLEIVERB_PROPERTIES) is invoked, the control opens a modal property dialog box that contains the control’s property pages."  I haven't been able to find anything about how to invoke a control's verbs, either.

Answer (score 0):

As I was about to ask this question over on reddit since I don't have an answer here yet, it occurred to me that one would want to invoke a control's property page from the control's container, not the control itself.  So, I went to my test application, typed my instance's variable name, and Intellisense showed me that the control has a property named ShowPropertyPages().